# Array Object in a scope showing empty while reading in a child html page- angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an array object in my angualr js file which while trying to console showing the results in js file. When I am trying to use the same object in a html file it is shown as empty.

Here is my code so far:

```
$scope.testarray=[];
$rootScope.$on('rootScope:testarray', function () {
         $scope.testarray = UserDataService.testarray;//this is read from a api service
         console.log("test"+ $scope.testarray) 
//prints on the console as :: test[object Object]
 $scope.showdialog('testdialog.html');
       });

$scope.showdialog= function ( id) {

        $mdDialog.show({
             scope: $scope.$new(),
             templateUrl: id
        });
   }
```

testdialog.html

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl"> <!-- same controller as the above function!-->

    <div >
    <div layout="column"  layout-padding flex>

   <b> <span>{{ testarray}}</span></b>


</div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

on the dialog it is printed as `{}`

Any help to say where am I going wrong. I am not seeing issue with the usage.

Comment: can u provide a plunker with sample data

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a different `$scope` inside dialog which is not the `$scope` of controller holding `testarray`

In the docs of `mddialouge` there is some option called `locals: { employee: $scope.userName }`

Use `locals` to add local values used in dialog.

```
$mdDialog.show({
             controller: 'DialogController',
             locals: {testarray : $scope.testarray}
             templateUrl: id
        });
```

Try adding a controller for the dialog to inject the `locals` into.

```
angular
.module('yourApp')
.controller('DialogController', function ($scope, testarray) {
  // items is injected in the controller, not its scope!
  $scope.testarray = testarray;
});
```

Comment: My problem is not in the js file or showing dialog, when I am trying to console the object any where in the js it is printing correct. It is only in js it is shown as empty. I tired your option too it didnt work.Any different way to use it in html?

Comment: The locals are available for `DI` in the controller set for mdDialog. Get it and add it to `$scope`.

Comment: That array is anyway in rootscope, removing controller directive from html worked. thnaks anyway

Comment: Also your `testarray` is probably a Promise or Observable, can you add the API calling part as well?